# Why did I get the no-unused-expressions error on "npm start" here in my case

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, publish, lint

I'm learning to create an NPM Libraries and publish to NPM. I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/jimjunior/how-to-create-an-npm-library-from-react-components-2m2).

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-library-test-jrhhe?file=/src/App.js) that works OK but can't test the npm link there.

It's working - I can use my published to NPM, npm package simply doing like so:

```
import returnLibrary from "react-library-test";
```

But when I do [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link) to debug my local copy of the react-library-test then it refuse to compile I think it's some form of strict mode on because I get this:

[image: enter image description ere]

It's hard to see were the mistake is because the "Line 11:261:  Expected an assignment.....". When I go into the index.cjs.js it looks like this at Line 11:261:

[image: enter image description ere]

Also why is the error messages regarding the dev folder files hmmm... I have linked the library look here;

[image]

I search for an answer and there are many similar answers about this but nothing works for me.

The library is simple just this:

index.js

```
import AwesomeButton from  './button.jsx'

const returnLibrary = () => {
    return {
        AwesomeButton: AwesomeButton
        // you can add ere oter components tat you want to export
    }
}
export default returnLibrary();
```

button.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./button.css";

const AwesomeButton = (props) => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.variant) {
      if (props.variant === "primary") {
        setColor("#0077ff");
      } else if (props.variant === "secondary") {
        setColor("#ff0062");
      } else if (props.variant === "success") {
        setColor("#0f8000");
      } else {
        setColor("#949393");
      }
    }
  }, [props.variant]);
  const { children } = props;

  return (
    <button
      className="buttonComponent"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: color,
      }}
    >
      {children.toUpperCase()}
    </button>
  );
};

export default AwesomeButton;
```

And I use it like this after I have done "npm link react-library-test" (it's strange because it works when not linking):

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
// import returnLibrary from "./react-library/src/index";
import returnLibrary from "react-library-test";

function App() {
  const { AwesomeButton } = returnLibrary;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AwesomeButton variant="secondary">sdsadda</AwesomeButton>
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React 
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "react-library-test",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "description": "your description",
    "main": "dist/index.cjs.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "rollup -c"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "react",
        "keywords"
    ],
    "author": "Hans Erik Hellberg",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
        "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.2.2",
        "rollup-plugin-sourcemaps": "^0.6.3",
        "rollup-plugin-styles": "^3.12.2",
        "rollup-plugin-visualizer": "^5.5.2"
    }
}
```

rollup config

```
import styles from "rollup-plugin-styles";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");

// the entry point for the library
const input = "src/index.js";

//
var MODE = [
  {
    fomart: "cjs",
  },
  {
    fomart: "esm",
  },
  {
    fomart: "umd",
  },
];

var config = [];

MODE.map((m) => {
  var conf = {
    input: input,
    output: {
      // then name of your package
      name: "react-awesome-buttons",
      file: `dist/index.${m.fomart}.js`,
      format: m.fomart,
      exports: "auto",
    },
    // this externelizes react to prevent rollup from compiling it
    external: ["react", 'react-dom', /@babel\/runtime/],
    plugins: [
      // these are babel comfigurations
      babel({
        exclude: "node_modules/**",
        plugins: ["@babel/transform-runtime"],
        babelHelpers: "runtime",
      }),
      // this adds sourcemaps
      // sourcemaps(),
      // this adds support for styles
      styles({
        postcss: {
          plugins: [autoprefixer()],
        },
      }),
    ],
  };
  config.push(conf);
});

export default [...config];
```

Testing to check if npm link is in affect:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by reading [the docs](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).

> This problem can also come up when you use npm link or an equivalent. In that case, your bundler might “see” two Reacts — one in application folder and one in your library folder. Assuming myapp and mylib are sibling folders, one possible fix is to run npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react from mylib. This should make the library use the application’s React copy.

The first error:

[image]

Was that in the package.json I did not change "main" to the src folder. Just doing that and npm link to peer app node_folders React fixed this problem.

(Just don't forget after "npm run build" of the lib to change back the package.json "main" to src folder.